# Termdebug won't show messages back from openocd

Tags: terminal, debugging

I am working with a microcontroller (stm32f4) and I am attempting to debug it by connecting `Termdebug` to `openocd`.

Everything works nicely with the exception that the messages sent back from `openocd` (server) to `Termdebug` (client) are not displayed in any `Termdebug` window (I expected them to be displayed in the gbd window).

For example, if I run `(gdb) monitor reg` I would expect to have the content of the microcontroller's registers displayed in the Termdebug's gdb window, but unfortunately that does not happen.

This is what is in my `.vimrc`

```
g:termdebug_config = {}
var debugger_path = "/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.macos64_1.1.100.202310310803/tools/bin/"
g:termdebug_config['command'] = debugger_path .. "arm-none-eabi-gdb"
```

If instead of using `Termdebug` I use another terminal window (I am using iTerm2) running as `arm-none-eabi-gdb` client connected to the same openocd server, then the messages sent back from the server are correctly displayed.

I am using MacVim 9.1.

Comment: You might also post on the mailing list or on GitHub

Comment: Done. I placed the question in vim-use Google group. Not sure if it is moderated because I cannot see my post there.

Comment: yes, it is moderated for the initial message. I just approved. But not sure if you have more luck over there.